# specify which button to move up wth soft keyboard in Android

Tags: android, button, android-relativelayout

I have multiple buttons in my layout aligned to bottom, when I want to type into an Edittext and the soft keyboard shows, how can I specify which button to move up with the soft keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use following in your EditText :-

```
android:nextFocusUp="@+id/edtTest"
```

Comment: So edtTest is the ID of the button i want to move up with the keyboard?

Comment: it is id of the EditText To which you want to set focus next

Comment: You didn't get my question, when the soft keyboard pops up how can i specify which view to move up with the keyboard?i dont want all the views at the bottom to move up i want to specify which.